# Claws Mail: import messages + folder structure from Thunderbird

Tags: linux, email, thunderbird

I've exported a folder structure with several messages and subdirectories from Thunderbird to mbox files. I'm trying to import this to Claws via `file>import mbox file...` but, so far, it works only for one single folder instead of nested subdirectories.

**Question**

1. Is it possible to import archive messages + folder structure to Claws? What formats?
2. Is it possible to import archive messages + folder structure from Thunderbird to Claws?

Comment: mbox doesn't contain folders at all. Use Maildir format instead or a shared imap server.

Comment: @IporSircer _> "mbox doesn't contain folders at all."_ Thunderbird has two options 1) `Tools > ImportExportTools > Export folder with subfolders (with structure)` and 2) `Tools > ImportExportTools > Export folder with subfolders (simple)`. Therefore, such description seems to suggest that Thunderbird indeed export folders information.

Comment: That is not a standard mbox format, it's _mboxrd_: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mbox#Modified_mbox . It can be only read by thunderbird. As i said, use Maildir, which contains folders.

Comment: Mind to briefly explain (just the initial steps would be fine) how to export Thunderbird into Maildir and how to import Maildir into Claws ?

Answer (score 1):

You might try `tbird2claws.py` from https://www.claws-mail.org/tools.php though I have to admit, I have never used it. It will convert a local Thunderbird folders to local Claws MH folders.

Mozillazine [recommend using KMail as an intermediate](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Importing_and_exporting_your_mail#Mbox_files) as it supports more formats than Thunderbird, but I don't see an easy way that helps in this situation...

(What I always use is [`imapsync`](https://github.com/imapsync/imapsync), for IMAP to IMAP moves, which may not be an option for you.)

Comment: Just tried `tbird2claws.py` but, so far, it didn't worked. Several error lines. Briefly: `IOERROR: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './lock'`

Comment: _> "as it supports more formats than Thunderbird"_ AFAICS, the problem is not Thunderbird, instead is Claws which only supports mbox to import (no subdirectories).

Comment: I'm gonna post my original question in another way: Is it possible to import archive messages + folder structure to Claws? What formats?